# rails app, how to add arm as a platform on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, capistrano

I have a rails app and the Gemfile and Gemfile lock are part of the repo.  Locally, we develop on Ubuntu x86, but we are trying to deploy to Ubuntu-arm (trying to take advantage of AWS cheaper gravitons).  When bundling, I get

```
rake stderr: /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.12.5-x86_64-linux in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I don't know if the word "X86_64" is a red herring or not, but anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` should sort you out taken from `https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#supported-platforms`